# More than 2 video after each other without converting in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, vlc

I have tried with VLC and ffplay/FFmpeg.

I can create a video with ffmpeg but that is slow... I need to see more than 2 (this can be 10 videos or more) videos after each other and play out this one long video.

ffmpeg -i "+ file1 + " -i " + file2 + " -filter_complex hstack "+ name +".mkv";

This is the code that FFmpeg using to stack 2 video horisontally. But here i need to convert the video and only 2 videos.

Anyone have something to help me?

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: With VLC i have tried to make mosaic. Witth ffplay i have tried to put videos after each other. With ffmpeg the code: ffmpeg -i "+ file1 + " -i " + file2 + " -filter_complex hstack "+ name +".mkv";
this is in ffmpeg so i cant play it out and only 2 videos.

Comment: It would better if you post your code in the question

Comment: The problem is that i did not find any code that can be used here.

Comment: Please be more specific in the description. Also I don't get why it's tagged C#?

Comment: Because I need something in c#.
I just need to put more than 2 videos after each other.

Comment: @Zsolvi It is not clear what you want to do. *"I just need to put more than 2 videos after each other"* It seems like you want to concatenate videos and play them in sequence, one after the other. Is this what you want to do? Or do you want to play them all at once in a mosaic? Do you just want to play them, or do you need to encode?

Comment: I want to play them all at once in mosaic. In one row.